# Why is an article needed in “café au lait”, but not in “verre à vin”?

Tags: prépositions, articles

I'm confused as to why I have generally seen à followed by article + noun, i.e.

> café au lait
>   visite à l'américaine
>   larmes aux yeux

But sometimes à sits alone without an article, like

> verre à vin
>   bar à vins

I know it can't just be the *vin*. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: *verre à eau, verre à bière, vere à pied, verre à dent* : it's not just *vin* indeed.

Comment: Same with fourchette, cuillère, etc.

Comment: _verre à vin_, but _coq au vin_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some meanings of the preposition *à* require the definite article, others don't.

- *café **au** lait* = coffee **containing** milk
- *visite **à** l'américaine* = American-**style** visit
- *larmes **aux** yeux* = tears *at the* eyes

vs.

- *verre **à** vin* = glass **for** wine
- *bar **à** vins* = bar **for** wine

Generally speaking, if you'd translate as **for** (i.e. if *à* expresses a purpose, a destination), then there is no article. Another case where there is no article is if *à* expresses a method — note that the distinction between method and ingredients (which do take an article) can occasionally be subtle. Objects made of distinguishable parts generally fall under the method case — the ingredients case is mostly for mixtures.

- *bateau **à** vapeur* = boat **that operates with** steam
- *bateau **à** voile* = boat **that operates with** a sail, boat **one of whose parts is** a sail
- *verre **à** pied* = glass **one of whose parts is** a stem

Related:

- *verre **de** vin* = glass **of** wine, glass **containing** wine
- *planche **de** bois* = plank **entirely made of** wood